# what happens on yum downgrade?

Tags: rpm, yum

When yum downgrade is run on an installed package, does yum first delete the package and then re-install the previous package?
As a corollary, what argument is passed to the %preun scriptlet of the package on yum downgrade, 0 or 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. From a quick skim of the yum 3.2.22 sources (from my CentOS 5 machine) it looks like it is a single transaction that is remove + install. Which would make me think `%preun` would get `1` passed to it.

The built-in help for yum.YumBase.downgrade also has this to say:

```
$ python
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jan  9 2013, 06:47:03)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yum
>>> help(yum.YumBase.downgrade)
Help on method downgrade in module yum:

downgrade(self, po=None, **kwargs) unbound yum.YumBase method
    Try to downgrade a package. Works like:
    % yum shell <<EOL
    remove  abcd
    install abcd-<old-version>
    run
    EOL
```

Comment: My testing appears to show that %preun gets 1 passed to it. I'd like to be able to distinguish between and upgrade and a downgrade in the %preun section, i.e. I want to run some code on downgrade but not on upgrade, but I think %preun gets 1 passed in both cases.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it looked like you would get. I don't think you can tell, in `%preun`, whether this is a downgrade or an upgrade. What are you trying to do during a downgrade anyway?

Comment: For historical reasons we have an rpm which applies changes to my.cnf (mysql configuration file) using a load of sed commands, checks if my.cnf has changed and if so restarts mysql with the new my.cnf. What I want to is to take a backup of the old my.cnf during the upgrade, and then restore the backup during a downgrade. I should add that soon we will be moving to managing my.cnf via puppet, so this issue will go away.

Comment: Use rpm package versioned copies and let each package check for (and copy into place) the appropriate `my.cnf.%{version}` during installation?